# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt":"^7.1.0","babel-p'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to create a new create an app, but whatever I do, I get same error.

> :npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt":"^7.1.0","babel-p'

I think there is some problem with babel.

```
C:\Users\Augustus\Desktop>npx create-react-app myapp

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Augustus\Desktop\myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt":"^7.1.0","babel-p'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:


Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\Augustus\Desktop
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

## force a reinstall

usually you can fix these kinds of errors by forcing a reinstall

try

`npm cache clean --force`

or

`yarn --force`

depending on if you are using npm or yarn for package management

Answer (score 0):

After forcing a reinstall, if you see that you are still getting the same error, check your internet connection. I had the same issue until I switched to a faster provider (in my third world country, internet can be slow at times) after which it immediately installed as it should have.